# Error while installing kiex version manager of elixir

Tags: versioning, elixir

I am using UBUNTU 16.04 . I installed the kiex with CURL . But while I run `kiex list known` it does not show anything and throws an not find command error.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What is kiex -v output?

Comment: You're confident that Kiex is supported on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: although it's not an answer to your question, you can try [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf). It solves same problem as kiex

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci yes it is supported on 16.04 .

Comment: @AlexTroush it wasn't showing anything before ..

Comment: @SergeiSilnov I will definitely look into it .

Comment: To all of you, It was my mistake. I did not added the `curl download-uri && move-it` .Now it is okay.

Answer (score 2):

What you mean by *I installed the kiex with CURL.* `cURL` is not installation tool. It just downloads file(s) from some `URL` and nothing more. When `kiex` command doesn't work it is because it is not installed. If you see something like `bash: kiex: command not found` it is simply because there is not any executable file named `kiex` in your `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks ... Your answer made my problem easier . I noticed that I did not `&&` move the source from download place . After `curl` download. Thanks .